# Custom label on shipping service in Checkout

Tags: commerce

I am grouping multiple products of an order and ask buyer to select a shipping service for each group.(because they get dispatched from different locations and have different delivery options)

This works ok, I can see the summarised shipping services at the checkout review (e.g. a line for each service with a value of service cost times number of groups this has been selected for).

However I cannot manage to label each shipping line item properly so that we would know what shipping was selected for which group/product. 
I am using the flat rate module. The label on checkout review pane is still the title of the shipping service as defined in the backend.

After modifying the line_item_label, the line item shipping service display_title or title, I still get the name of the shipping service instead of my custom text.

I am not using Rules because my logic is too complex. dpm-ing the line items shows the altered title.

Any ideas what to do?